# jQuery DataTables JavaScript move search boxes

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, datatables

Evening All,

I'm using this jQuery example from Datatables

https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

I would like to place the Search Boxes that currently appear on the bottom of the page underneath the headings e.g. so I still have the bold headings that have the ability to sort but below are the filter boxes where I can filter if needs be.

There are some comments on the page with JavaScript claiming to work however I just cant get anything to work exactly how I would like it!?!

Any help would be much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following fiddle has minimal changes in an attempt to achieve what you describe in your question (moving the input sort boxes below the table header titles):

https://jsfiddle.net/r1dbw6u2/4/

The javascript changes featured can be summarized as:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
$('#example thead th').each( function () {
    var title = $(this).text();
    $(this).append( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
} );

// DataTable
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

// Apply the search
table.columns().every( function () {
    var that = this;

    $( 'input', this.header() ).on( 'click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    } );

    $( 'input', this.header() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
        if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
            that
                .search( this.value )
                .draw();
        }
    } );
} );
```

Comment: I have produced this result once already however when you click in the search box It also sorts e.g. A-Z on that filter box. 

I would like the search function to be separate to the sort but cant get it to work correctly!!!

Comment: check out the latest updates (updated fiddle, added stopPropagation to javascript summary)

Comment: You are a god!!! Thank you very much, this has been racking my brain for such a long time!